# PHP JSON Array Formatting

Tags: php, arrays, json

Let me first start off, sorry for the confusing title. I didn't know how to exactly describe it but here goes. So I am querying a database for string. If there is only 1 result found then it is relatively easy to create an array, fill it with information, encode JSON and return that. I am confused as to when there are multiple results. The code below is what I am using but I highly doubt it is correct. I can't encode it into JSON format using my method which is what I need. If you can help at least point me in the correct direction, I would be more than grateful! Thank you!

---

PHP:

```
if ($action == 'profile') {
    while ($pson = mysql_fetch_array($personQuery)) {
        $typeSearch = 'profile';
        $profQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE ColumnName LIKE '$query'");
        $compQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableName2 WHERE ColumnName LIKE '$query'");
        if ($profQuery && mysql_num_rows($profQuery) > 0) {
            $personQueryRows = mysql_num_rows($profQuery);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($profQuery)) {
                if ($compQuery && mysql_num_rows($compQuery) > 0) {
                    while ($com = mysql_fetch_array($compQuery)) {
                        if (mysql_num_rows($profQuery) > 1) { 
                            $compQueryRows = mysql_num_rows($compQuery);
                            if ($compQueryRows > 0) {
                                $compReturn = "true";
                            } else {
                                $compReturn = "false";
                            }
                            $nameArray = Array(
                                "success"=>"true",
                                "date"=>date(),
                                "time"=>$time,
                                "action"=>$action,
                                "returned"=>"true"
                            );
                            global $result;
                            for ($i=1;$i<=$personQueryRows;$i++) {
                                $nameResult[$i]=Array(
                                    "id"=>$row['id'],
                                    "name"=>$row['name'],
                                    "gender"=>$row['gender'],
                                    "comp"=>$row['company'],
                                    "queryType"=>"profile"
                                );
                                $result = array_merge($nameArray, $nameResult[$i]);
                            }
                            $encodedJSON = json_encode($result);
                            echo $encodedJSON;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Returned JSON:

```
{"success":"true","date":"Jun 29 2012","time":"14:43:16","action":"profile","returned":"true","id":"14321","name":"John Smith","gender":"male","comp":"ABC Studios, LLC.","queryType":"profile"}
{"success":"true","date":"Jun 29 2012","time":"14:43:16","action":"profile","returned":"true","id":"292742","name":"John Smith","gender":"male","comp":"DEF Studios, LLC.","queryType":"profile"}
```

JavaScript error (when parsing JSON):

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

---

P.S. I am just getting started with PHP Arrays, and JSON formatting so I apologize if this is totally wrong. Still in the learning phase.

Comment: Do you see? `,"queryType":"profile"}{"success":"true",` Two touching `{}{}`! Aren't you accidentally print the result json twice? I edited your json, added a newline between the two objects.

Comment: Yes I do, but how do I go about fixing this? Again this is one of my first attempts working with multi-dimensional JSON arrays.

Comment: Is your `echo $encodedJSON;` wrapped into another loop that you didn't copied here? `json_encode` won't generate such an output.

Comment: Your problem is that this code is running in a larger loop that you haven't shown. Rather than `$encodedJSON = json_encode($result); echo $encodedJSON;` there, you should simply do `$outerArray[] = $result;` and convert `$outerArray` to JSON after the loop and echo that. Obviously you should declare `$outerArray = array()` before the loop as well ;-)

Comment: There are no other loops wrapping this code. There are 2 `while` loops above this but that shouldn't cause the code to run multiple times, should it?

Comment: @jtorraca I think we need to see the full code, there is obviously something happening outside the part you have shown that is causing this. **Edit** Actually, I notice the `global` - is this code within a function that is being called more than once?

Comment: If it is not on the php side, then it must be on the javascript side: are you concatenating multiple json strings into one?

Comment: @DaveRandom I have added the full PHP code to help you

Comment: @biziclop I know it is not on the JavaScript side because on the `Network` tak of the Web Inspector, the returned JSON is like above with the `{ }{ }`. It has to be on the PHP side.

Comment: No it's definitely the PHP, it's wrapped in a three outer loops. For future reference, if you find yourself closing 8 sets of braces in one place, there's probably a better (more readable) way of doing it. Give me a few minutes to pull that apart and work out what you should be doing.

Comment: There are 3 loops around the json_encode part. Move it out of the loops.

Comment: D'you know what, quick fix because I really don't have the energy ATM, change it to [this](http://codepad.org/8M5GCKNb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're building up $nameResult[$i], but then you do:

```
$result = array_merge($nameArray, $nameResult[$i]);
```

You're doing that in each iteration of that for loop (once for each of the rows you got back), meaning that each time, you're clobbering $result.

After you finish that for loop, you then take whatever $result finally is (meaning the last $personQueryRows), and then json_encode it.

Looking at your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257490/jquery-parse-multidimensional-array), it looks like what you should really be doing is before the loop where you go over $personQueryRows:

```
$output=$nameArray;
```

And then replace the array_merge line with:

```
$output[] = $nameResult[$i];
```

That last line will append the $result array onto the $output array as a new array member, meaning that it's nesting the array, which is what you'll need for your nested JSON.

Comment: Based on the error message, the JS that is throwing the error is `JSON.parse(str);`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
global $result;
$result = array();
.......    

if ($action == 'profile') {
  while{{{{{{{{...}}}}}}}}}}}

  $encodedJSON = json_encode( $result );
  echo $encodedJSON;
}
```

Comment: Only problem is that this will only output `$result` from that last iteration. I would guess the desired result would be a collection of all the `$result`s in an array

Comment: Yes, he should consider ernie's answer too, that array_merge thing smells badly.

Comment: That whole code makes me recoil in horror frankly - nested iteration of *3* result sets, and as I commented before, 8 sets of braces closing in one place, and probably a gaping SQL inject hole as well (I'm guessing). But we were all young once... ;-)

Comment: We are so close, but there is a minor problem. It is still echoing $nameArray within the arrays. So it is `{"0":{"success":"true","id":1234", "name":"John Smith"}, "1":{"success":"true", "id":5678", "name":"Carl Smith"}}`, How do I fix this? Is it because I am merging the arrays and then added them to the outerArray? Btw, There are a bunch of else statements where the 8 sets of brackets close., they don't just end there. I felt like those else statements weren't necessary to the development of a correct answer.

Comment: Maybe you should write `$result[] = array_merge($nameArray, $nameResult[$i]);`  This syntax: `$array[]='a new element'` appends a new element to the array.

Comment: @jtorraca see my answer below - you're only get the last result due to the way you keep re-assigning $result.  I'm also assuming you want your JSON output to look like what you had in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257490/jquery-parse-multidimensional-array